# Can someone please tell me what am doing wrong in my widget

Tags: java, android, rss

I am developing an RSS feed file.rss reader widget that retrieves feeds from news24. When I run the application it says there is a nullpointer exception that I don't understand.

Here is my widget provider class

```
  RemoteViews views;
Intent mIn;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManagerGlobal;
static ArrayList<String> mStorytitles = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> mLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<NewsItem> mNews = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
private static final String READ_MORE = "ReadMoreTag";
static Random random = new Random();
private ProcessInBackground pr = new ProcessInBackground();

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int count = appWidgetIds.length;


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        pr.execute();
        //new ProcessInBackground().execute();
        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.activity_main);
        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.id.tvHeading);
        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.id.tvTitle);
        int randomValue = random.nextInt(mNews.size());
        mIn = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        mIn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mIn.setData(Uri.parse(mNews.get(randomValue).getLink()));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, mIn, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnreadmore, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
    }
}

private class ProcessInBackground extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvHeading, "Getting stories");
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, "Please wait..");
        appWidgetManagerGlobal.updateAppWidget(mIn.getIntExtra("id", 0), views);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String...params) {
        mNews = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
        try{
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            int response = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStream inStream = httpConn.getInputStream();

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(inStream);
                Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();

                NodeList nList = element.getElementsByTagName("item");
                if (nList != null && nList.getLength() > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++){
                        Node item = nList.item(i);
                        String title = item.getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
                        String link = item.getChildNodes().item(5).getTextContent();
                        mNews.add(new NewsItem(title,link));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e){
            Log.d("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Log.d("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
            Log.d("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SAXException e){
            Log.d("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        int ranVal = random.nextInt(mNews.size());
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvHeading, "Top Story");
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTitle, mNews.get(ranVal).getTitle());
        appWidgetManagerGlobal.updateAppWidget(mIn.getIntExtra("id", 0), views);
    }

}
```

And I added in my mainfest file I added the right information and I referenced my priver information in meta-data

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.labl2.news24" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_name"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_name"
        android:label="News24" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

The error that my app throws is this

Answer (score 0):

You initializing `RemoteViews views`too late. In your for loop you are executing the task first, after that you initializing your views object. And in preExecute() you refer on the null object.

So, first inflate the view and then execute the task.